# how to update database when adding conatct to target list in Sugar CRM

Tags: php, mysql, suitecrm

I`ve been trying to update custom table when contact getting added to Target List in Sugar Crm.
I I tried to achieve this with after save logic hook. But nothing is happening. Even no error.
Tried out logic hook

```
<?php
$hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(
    1,
    'after_save example',
    'custom/modules/ProspectLists/after_save_class.php',
    'after_save_class',
    'after_save_method'
);
```

```
class after_save_class
{
    function after_save_method($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
        print_r($bean);exit;
        error_log("======================================================================================================hook is working");
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to catch this contact adding action and write a custom logic ?

Comment: have you added in code which is triggered when the logic hook is called?

Comment: No. Just logging message for now

Comment: print_r($bean);exit;
Do you think that code will be executed after "exit" statment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suit crm 7.10 does not support this functionality (Sugar 6.5.25).
Best way to achieve this is creating a scheduler and manually update the DB